# Which way does this tension pulley go?

Tags: derailleur

Took apart my Shimano Acera derailleur cage to clean it up a bit and didn't bother to note the shape of the tension pulley which is a bit thicker on one side. It seems like it would be shaped this way for a reason since the guide pulley is symmetrical. Should the thicker side face toward or away from the wheel?

[image]

Edit: Here's a close-up showing an arrow or #1:

[image]

Update:

Per user in comment section, the arrow is indeed an indicator as to which way the pulley should be installed. See below excerpt taken from an unrelated Shimano derailleur model:

https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-TRRD001-00-ENG.pdf

- Depending on the model, the guide pulley has arrows on it to indicate the direction of rotation. Install the guide pulley so that the arrows are
  pointing counterclockwise when looking at the outer side of the derailleur.
- The tension pulley has an arrow on it to indicate the direction of rotation. Install the tension pulley so that the arrow is pointing clockwise when
  looking at the outer side of the derailleur.

Comment: Generally speaking, the cuppy thing goes on the outside.

Comment: Does the jockey wheel have direction of rotation arrows printed on it? If so that will tell you which way around it should be installed. Note that the top and bottom wheels are different, the top wheel usually has a couple of mm lateral play built in.

Comment: @DanielRHicks By outside, you mean facing away from the wheel?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Nope, there's nothing on the tension pulley except for the number 1 and also the acronym POM next to a recycle symbol

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Actually, that number 1 could also be an arrow after closer inspection. Updating question

Comment: @oscilatingcretin - Yep, you should be able to see it (and squirt lubricant behind it).

Comment: @oscilatingcretin That is definitely an arrow, not a 1.

Comment: Looks like a 1 to me - does the other jockey wheel in the set bear a "2" or a "0" perhaps?  Or an arrow in the other direction ?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus See update at end of question. You should post your comment as answer.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin "POM" is the recycling code showing what kind of plastic it is, to aid sorting and avoid contaminating batches with the wrong plastic.  POM is Polyoxymethylene which is also called Acetal, an "engineering thermoplastic"  Also sold under brand names like delrin.

Comment: @Criggie The guide pulley has no arrow (or numeral). My guess is that it doesn't require a particular direction of rotation due to its symmetry. The t-pulley probably needs to rotate in a certain way due to its asymmetrical design, perhaps as a means to somehow balance/offset tension forces (I am just guessing here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often jockey wheels have direction of rotation arrows printed on them. That will tell you which way around it should be installed.

Note that the top and bottom wheels are typically different, the top wheel usually has a couple of mm lateral play built in.

Answer (score 6):

I checked several from a variety of years. If they weren't symmetrical the thicker side was toward the wheel.